# MSTest Data source - pass on a custom object collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I am creating a selenium framework using MSTest. The data which is being used is quite complex and it is a collection of objects. The objects are in a List.

Each of the item in the list represent a test case. During the [TestInitialize] phase, I create this list.

Given this scenario, could any one please help me as how to pass on this list data to the [testmethod] function.

I googled it and I found we can use           **[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource")]**

But not sure how to pass this list to the testmethod

Any pointers on how this can be achieved will be very helpful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with MSTest, you can currently only hook up DataSource() with a connection string to a datasource (eg. sql).

It is possible with Nunit to achieve this using [TestCaseSource](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5)

There is also a [NuGet package](https://github.com/Thwaitesy/MSTestHacks) to extend MSTest to include this functionality

I have also read they are going to be adding this feature to MSTest, it is currently in preview and possibly only supports UWP and Desktop Apps.